# Code golf: the Mandelbrot set

Tags: code-golf, rosetta-stone, fractals, mandelbrot

Usual rules for the code golf. Here is an implementation in python as an example

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new("RGB", (300,300))
for i in xrange(300):
    print "i = ",i
    for j in xrange(300):
        x0 = float( 4.0*float(i-150)/300.0 -1.0)
        y0 = float( 4.0*float(j-150)/300.0 +0.0)
        x=0.0
        y=0.0
        iteration = 0
        max_iteration = 1000
        while (x*x + y*y <= 4.0 and iteration < max_iteration):
            xtemp = x*x - y*y + x0
            y = 2.0*x*y+y0
            x = xtemp
            iteration += 1
        if iteration == max_iteration:
            value = 255 
        else:
            value = iteration*10 % 255
        print value 
        im.putpixel( (i,j), (value, value, value))

im.save("image.png", "PNG")
```

The result should look like this

[image: Mandelbrot set]

Use of an image library is allowed. Alternatively, you can use ASCII art. This code does the same

```
for i in xrange(40):
    line = []
    for j in xrange(80):
        x0 = float( 4.0*float(i-20)/40.0 -1.0)
        y0 = float( 4.0*float(j-40)/80.0 +0.0)
        x=0.0
        y=0.0
        iteration = 0
        max_iteration = 1000
        while (x*x + y*y <= 4.0 and iteration < max_iteration):
            xtemp = x*x - y*y + x0
            y = 2.0*x*y+y0
            x = xtemp
            iteration += 1
        if iteration == max_iteration:
            line.append(" ")
        else:
            line.append("*")
    print "".join(line)
```

The result

```
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
**************************************** ***************************************
**************************************** ***************************************
**************************************** ***************************************
**************************************** ***************************************
**************************************** ***************************************
**************************************** ***************************************
**************************************** ***************************************
***************************************   **************************************
*************************************       ************************************
************************************         ***********************************
***********************************           **********************************
************************************         ***********************************
*************************************       ************************************
***********************************           **********************************
********************************                 *******************************
****************************                         ***************************
*****************************                       ****************************
****************************                         ***************************
************************   *                         *   ***********************
***********************    *                         *    **********************
******************** *******                         ******* *******************
****************************                         ***************************
******************************                     *****************************
*****************************  *        *        *  ****************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
```

**Edit**:

Rules for the ASCII art:

- size in rows/columns is parametrized and the code must work with any valid value.
- at least three level of differentiation in density depending on the iteration count (so my prototype up there is not compliant)
- oriented horizontally (so my prototype up there is not compliant)
- critical parameters are fixed (max iteration = 1000, runaway value x*x + y*y <= 4.0)

Rules for the graphic:

- size in rows/columns is parametrized and the code must work with any valid value.
- at least three level of colors, gray scale
- oriented horizontally (my prototype is compliant)

Comment: `Alternatively, you can use ASCII art.` <- nice.

Comment: ASCII ART? is that a Tele-Tubby?

Comment: Thanks. Now I can't look at that pic again without shivering.

Answer (score 42):

There was a perl solution already some years ago
posted in [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=329492), it reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 $r=25; $c=80;
                                              $xr=6;$yr=3;$xc=-0.5;$dw=$z=-4/
                                              100;local$";while($q=$dr=rand()
                                             /7){$w+=$dw;$_=join$/,map{$Y=$_*
                                             $yr/$r;
  join""                                    ,map{$                  x=$_*$
 xr/$c;($                                   x,$y)=                 ($xc+$x
  *cos($                                   w)-$Y*               sin$w,$yc+
                                           $x*sin              ($w)+$Y*cos
  $w);$                                   e=-1;$                    a=$b=0
;($a,$b)   =($u-$v+$x,2*$a*               $b+$y)                    while(
$ u=$a*$   a)+($v=$b*$b)<4.5  &&++$e     <15;if                     (($e>$
  q&&$e<   15)||($e==$q and   rand()     <$dr))  {$q=$e;($d0,$d1)   =($x,$
  y); }                        chr(+(   32,96,+  46,45,43,58,73,37  ,36,64
 ,32)[$                        e/1.5]   );}(-$   c/2)..($c/2)-1;}   (-$r/2
 )..($     r/2)-1;select$",     $",$", 0.015;                       system
$^O=~m     ~[wW]in~x?"cls":     "clear";print                       ;$xc=(
$d0+15     *$xc)/16;$yc=($       d1+15*$yc)/                        16;$_*=
1+$z for                         $xr,$yr;$dw                     *=-1 if rand
()<0.02;                          (++$i%110                      )||($z*=-1)}
```

which is a "Mandelbrot explorer".

(It rotates, zooms in & out, and scrolls randomly to examine regions 
of the Mandelbrot set it deems "interesting.", according to
it's creator.)

It doesn't exactly follow the specs named here but 
makes an interesting entry (imho). Maybe a simple
Mandlebrot is not very interesting for the perl gods ;.-)

Regards

rboo

Comment: ... and the crazy thing is: it really works. 
Just paste it into a text file 'mandel.pl' and 
start it in a linux console. The creator, 'blokhead'
(http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=137386) is
a well known contributor to the "Perl Monks" site.

Comment: also, resize terminal/xterm/putty to 80x24 for best results

Answer (score 25):

### J, greyscale graphical output with levels, 170 characters.

```
load'viewmat'
c=:>(<:;|:;0$])((2$>:@+:)$-:%~i:)300
(2.5*|:3 99$i._99)viewmat {:99&<.@;@(({:+4&<@:({.+1&{)@:*:);~(0{c)&+@({.-1&{)@:*:,:(1{c)&+@:+:@({.*1&{))^:99 c
```

[alt text http://i40.tinypic.com/2i7lm0.jpg](http://i40.tinypic.com/2i7lm0.jpg)

### J, graphical output with levels, 151 characters.

```
load'viewmat'
c=:>(<:;|:;0$])((2$>:@+:)$-:%~i:)99
viewmat {:99&<.@;@(({:+4&<@:({.+1&{)@:*:);~(0{c)&+@({.-1&{)@:*:,:(1{c)&+@:+:@({.*1&{))^:99 c
```

Output:

[alt text http://i40.tinypic.com/6ynxap.jpg](http://i40.tinypic.com/6ynxap.jpg)

### J, graphical output, 124 characters.

```
load'viewmat'
c=:>(<:;|:)((2$>:@+:)$-:%~i:)200
viewmat 4>:({.+{:)@:*:(5<.>@(({.c)&+@({.-{:)@:*:;({:c)&+@:+:@({.*{:)))^:999 c
```

Basically just runs "viewmat" on the ascii output.

[alt text http://i40.tinypic.com/etv5lf.jpg](http://i40.tinypic.com/etv5lf.jpg)

### J, ASCII, 101 characters.

```
c=:>(<:;|:)((2$>:@+:)$-:%~i:)20
4>:({.+{:)@:*:(5<.>@(({.c)&+@({.-{:)@:*:;({:c)&+@:+:@({.*{:)))^:999 c
```

Wasted 6 characters to properly parametrize the size.

**J, ASCII, 95 characters.**

```
c=:>(<:;|:)41 41$10%~i:20
4>:({.+{:)@:*:(5<.>@(({.c)&+@({.-{:)@:*:;({:c)&+@:+:@({.*{:)))^:999 c
```

It doesn't do multiple levels of greyscale yet.

Explanation (currently out of date, will update later):

```
i:20
```

Generate the list of integers from -20 to 20.

```
10%~i:20
```

Divide them all by 10 (`%` is divide, `~` is invert order of arguments.

```
41 41$10%~i:20
```

Fill this list into a 41x41 array, with wrapping.

```
(-&1;|:)41 41$`10%~i:20`
```

Append to this array a second array of the same size, but transposed. `-&1` subtracts one from each element, `;` is append, `|:` is transpose. Now we have a 2x41x41 array, where the first 41x41 array contains the "x0" values of each coordinate and the second contains the "y0" values.

```
4<:~({.+{:)@:*:(5<.>@(({.c)&+@:({.-{:)@:*:;({:c)&+@:+:@:({.*{:)))^:1000 ($c)$0
```

Wow. Let's break this up from the right.

```
($c)$0
```

This creates a second 2x41x41 array (the same size as c), filled with 0s. This is going to be the variable we're iterating on - basically the first array contains the "x" values and the second contains the "y" values.

`^:1000` means "Repeat the previous thing in parentheses 1000 times. This is our loop counter.

```
(5<.>@(({.c)&+@:({.-{:)@:*:;({:c)&+@:+:@:({.*{:))
```

This is the next big chunk. It's basically doing one iteration of the loop. First we generate x with `(({.c)&+@:({.-{:)@:*:`, then join `;` it to y `({:c)&+@:+:@:({.*{:)`

```
   (({.c)&+@:({.-{:)@:*:
```

This generates x (remember it's operating on that 2x41x41 array representing x and y). First it squares `*:` each element, then does `{. - {:`, or x^2 - y^2. `{.` selects the first 41x41 array and `{:` the second. `@:` joins functions together.

To x^2-y^2, we need to add x0 - this is the first 41x41 array of c so we can do this with `({.c)&+` - `&` curries `{.c` (x0) into `+`.

```
({:c)&+@:+:@:({.*{:)
```

We generate y in a similar fashion. First we pairwise multiply the input x `{.` and y `{:` arrays, double the result with `+:`, and add y0 `{:c`.

The last step of this function is simply `5<.>` - unboxing the join of the two new x and y arrays, and capping at 5 - it's ok since this function is monotonically increasing above 4, and we'll get out-of-bounds integers if we don't cap the values on each iteration.

```
4>:({.+{:)@:*:
```

The last step, once we've finished iterating. We square the x and y arrays `*:`, add them together `{.+{:`, and make a boolean array that's true for every element that's `>:` less than 4.

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 12):

Python 108 (was 122):

```
for a in range(900):print"\n.x"[(a%30>0)+(abs(reduce(lambda z,c:z*z+c,[a%30*.1-2+1j*(a/30*.1-1.5)]*30))<2)],
```

That last "30" is the iteration count, not one of the dimensions.
Output looks thus:

```
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . x . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . x x . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . x x . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . x . x x x x x . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . x x x x x x x x x . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . x x x x x x x x x x . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . x . . . x x x x x x x x x x . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . x x x . x x x x x x x x x x x x . . . . . 
. . . . . . . x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x . . . . . . 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . x x x . x x x x x x x x x x x x . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . x . . . x x x x x x x x x x . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . x x x x x x x x x x . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . x x x x x x x x x . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . x . x x x x x . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . x x . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . x x . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . x . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Now going to update based on the updated rules....

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell (185 chars, with all the features required in the question)

Using complex numbers and actually counting the required number of iterations (unlike the "simple" version in my other answer).

```
import Complex
i v=show(length$takeWhile((<=4).magnitude)$take 1000$iterate(\c->c*c+v)v)!!0
r t=[-2,4/read t-2..2]
main=getLine>>=(\[s,t]->mapM_ putStrLn[[i$x:+y|x<-r s]|y<-r t]).words
```

The dimensions of the resulting image are read from stdin. The output is "colored" according to the number of required iterations:

```
$ ./fract
60 30
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111112222222222222222111111111111111111111111111111
1111111112222222222222222222222222222111111111111111111111111
1111112222222222222222222222222222222222111111111111111111111
1112222222222222222222222222222222222222222111111111111111111
1222222222222222222222333333333322222222222221111111111111111
2222222222222222223333333344443333332222222222211111111111111
2222222222222233333333344458755443333322222222222111111111111
2222222222233333333344445568117544433333222222222211111111111
2222222233333333344445556711111765544333322222222221111111111
2222233333333444445562391112161568786443332222222222111111111
2223333334444455556681111111111111157544333222222222211111111
2333334445617677777911111111111111111854333222222222211111111
3333444456681131231111111111111111111654333322222222221111111
3444555671111111111111111111111111114644333322222222221111111
2569888111111111111111111111111111296544333322222222221111111
3444555671111111111111111111111111114644333322222222221111111
3333444456681131231111111111111111111654333322222222221111111
2333334445617677777911111111111111111854333222222222211111111
2223333334444455556681111111111111157544333222222222211111111
2222233333333444445562391112161568786443332222222222111111111
2222222233333333344445556711111765544333322222222221111111111
2222222222233333333344445568117544433333222222222211111111111
2222222222222233333333344458755443333322222222222111111111111
2222222222222222223333333344443333332222222222211111111111111
1222222222222222222222333333333322222222222221111111111111111
1112222222222222222222222222222222222222222111111111111111111
1111112222222222222222222222222222222222111111111111111111111
1111111112222222222222222222222222222111111111111111111111111
1111111111111112222222222222222111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 9):

### Delphi - <s>310</s> <s>249</s> <s>239</s> 224 chars

ASCII version. Uses 7 levels for gradient shading.

- Removed `program P;` and `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}` according to (suggested by Uwe Raabe);
- Inlined 1000 const (suggested by Uwe Raabe);
- Inlined `'8Oo;,. '` variable;
- Changed `word` to `integer` so that the loop variable can be negative, and then changed the loop range for I from `3..38` to `-5..30` so that `(I-8)` could be replaced by `I` (suggested by Eric Grange);
- Changed `1000` to `1e3` (suggested by Eric Grange)
- Changed type `Double` to `Real` (suggested by Luc Neville via e-mail)
- Removed brackets `while((x*x+y*y<=4)and(t<1000))do` --> `while(x*x+y*y<=4)and(t<1000)do` (suggested by Luc Neville via e-mail)
- Removed spaces between numbers that were followed by a keyword (so that `for j:=-5 to 30  do` becomes `for j:=-5to 30do`(Suggested by Neville via e-mail)
- Changed loop range to `for j:=8to 40do`, removing the negative sign, and changed integer back to word. Compensated this offset in the formula, by changing `x * x - y * y + i / 16 - 2;` to `x * x - y * y + i / 16 - 3`;

Unreadable version:

```
var n,x,y:Real;t,i,j:Word;begin for j:=8to 40do begin for i:=8to 65do begin x:=0;y:=0;t:=0;while(x*x+y*y<=4)and(t<1e3)do begin n:=x*x-y*y+i/16-3;y:=2*x*y+j/12-2;x:=n;inc(t)end;Write('8Oo;,. '[t mod 7+1])end;WriteLn;end;end.
```

Formatted code:

```
var
  n, x, y: Real;
  t, i, j: Word;
begin
  for j := 8 to 40 do
  begin
    for i := 8 to 65 do
    begin
      x := 0;
      y := 0;
      t := 0;
      while (x * x + y * y <= 4) and (t < 1e3) do
      begin
        n := x * x - y * y + i / 16 - 3;
        y := 2 * x * y + j / 12 - 2;
        x := n;
        inc(t)
      end;
      Write('8Oo;,. '[t mod 7 + 1])
    end;
    WriteLn;
  end;
end.
```

Output:

```
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;oooooooooooooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,,;;;;oooooooooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,, ; .,,,;;;oooooooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOOoooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,.. O   ,,,,;;;oooooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,,...8oo,8..,,,;;;;oooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOooo;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,,,.. Oo. ; 8...,,;;;;ooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOoo;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,,.   8OO    O8 ..,,;;;;oooooo
OOOOOOOOOOoo;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,..  O,oO8oo ,OOoO88,.,;;;;ooooo
OOOOOOOOOOo;;;;;;;;;;,,,....  o. .         OOO  ,;;;;;oooo
OOOOOOOOOO;;;;;;;;;,,......  o.,              o .,;;;;;ooo
OOOOOOOOOo;;;;;;,,. o     88O.                ;O.,;;;;;ooo
OOOOOOOOO;;;,,,,,.. ,,o;,oOo;                  o ,,;;;;;oo
OOOOOOOOO;,,,,,... 8o;   8;,                    .,,;;;;;oo
OOOOOOOOO,,,,,... Oo       .                   8.,,;;;;;oo
OOOOOOOOO,.,.  88oo o       ,                 , .,,;;;;;oo
OOOOOOOO                                     ,8 .,,;;;;;;o
OOOOOOOOO,.,.  88oo o       ,                 , .,,;;;;;oo
OOOOOOOOO,,,,,... Oo       .                   8.,,;;;;;oo
OOOOOOOOO;,,,,,... 8o;   8;,                    .,,;;;;;oo
OOOOOOOOO;;;,,,,,.. ,,o;,oOo;                  o ,,;;;;;oo
OOOOOOOOOo;;;;;;,,. o     88O.                ;O.,;;;;;ooo
OOOOOOOOOO;;;;;;;;;,,......  o.,              o .,;;;;;ooo
OOOOOOOOOOo;;;;;;;;;;,,,....  o. .         OOO  ,;;;;;oooo
OOOOOOOOOOoo;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,..  O,oO8oo ,OOoO88,.,;;;;ooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOoo;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,,.   8OO    O8 ..,,;;;;oooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOooo;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,,,.. Oo. ; 8...,,;;;;ooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,,...8oo,8..,,,;;;;oooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOOoooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,.. O   ,,,,;;;oooooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,, ; .,,,;;;oooooooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,,,,,;;;;oooooooooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooo;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;oooooooooooooooooo
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

Comment: Error: as g is a 1-based string you better write "g[t mod 7 + 1]".
You can reduce the overall length by inlining the constant m and removing the "program Mandel;" statement. The APPTYPE can be set in the commmand line for the compiler, so it also can be removed completely. This all makes 273 characters.

BTW, I like the new CTRL-D key in D2010...

Comment: @Uwe: good suggestions.. I've removed the compiler directive from the code, and got rid of the m constant. I also got rid of the g constant and used it as a literal like this: '8Oo;,. '[t mod 7+1], so the whole const section could be ditched. I've also removed temporary variables that were being cached, to just have them recalculated in every iteration. Saves a couple of characters at the cost of performance :)

Comment: You can still remove the "program" line as the compiler actually doesn't need it. This will save you another 10 chars.

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know you can just leave that line out. Good way to silence the compiler when you rename the file outside the IDE. However, if you try file/new/unit it messes up your code.

Comment: You can gain 3 more chars by changing the while to "while(x*x+y*y<=4)and(t<1e3)".
If I counted correctly, you can also gain by changing the integers from Word to Integer type and baking-in the i/j delta in the for loop (thus turning "(i-8)" into "i", saving 8 chars at the cost of 5).

Comment: Looks like an interesting level in Nethack

Answer (score 8):

**T-SQL (<strike>421</strike> 408 characters)**

```
declare @s varchar(max);
with
x(x)as(select CAST(-2.0 as real)union all select x+.01 from x where x<1),
y(y)as(select CAST(-1.1 as real)union all select y+.02 from y where y<1.1),
g(x,y,u,v,g)as(select x,y,x*0,y*0,0 from x,y union all select x,y,u*u-v*v+x,2*u*v+y,g+1 from g where g<24and u*u+v*v<4),
m(x,y,v)as(select x,y,case when x<-1.99 then char(10)end+substring(' .-''^"+oiexp**##$$$§§%%%@',COUNT(*),1)from g group by x,y)
select @s=@s+v from m order by y,x option(maxrecursion 400)
select @s
```

[Output is here:](http://gist.github.com/368999)

Comment: Even shorter than this: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Stupid-Coding-Tricks-The-TSQL-Madlebrot.aspx

Comment: well, that was the inspiration. :)

Comment: Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 300 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: my bad -- up to 400 and it should be fine. note that SSMS defaults to only displaying 256 characters per column by default (and it doesn't show newlines properly, so use `select cast(@s as xml)` to view the results

Answer (score 7):

### awk - 134 <strike>135</strike> chars

ASCII art, fully compliant. Fairly straightforward translation of the python reference implementation:

```
{for(j=-2;j<=2;j+=4/$2){for(i=-3;i<=1;i+=4/$1){for(x=y=k=0;x*x+y*y<=4&&++k<4^5;)
{t=x*x-y*y+i;y=2*x*y+j;x=t}printf"%d",log(k)}print""}}
```

test run

```
$ awk -f mandel.awk 
10 10
00000000000
00000000000
00000111000
00001116110
00011166610
00046666611
00011166610
00001116110
00000111000
00000000000
00000000000
```

and this is a **VT-100** art. Set the xterm to "unreadable" characters, then try a 400x200 set:

```
{for(j=-2;j<=2;j+=4/$2){for(i=-3;i<=1;i+=4/$1){for(x=y=k=0;x*x+y*y<=4&&++k<1000;)
{t=x*x-y*y+i;y=2*x*y+j;x=t}printf"\x1b[4%dm ",log(k)}print"\x1b[0m"}}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell (162 characters)

A (fairly) straight forward ASCII art version:

```
c(x,y)|x*x+y*y<4.0='x'
 |True='.'
i v w=c(iterate s(v,w)!!1000)where s(x,y)=(x*x-y*y+v,2*x*y+w)
main=mapM_ putStrLn[[i x y|x<-[-1.5,-1.45..0.5]]|y<-[1,0.9.. -1]]
```

#### Output:

```
$ ./a.out
.........................................
.........................................
..........................xxxx...........
..........................xxxx...........
....................x..xxxxxxxxxx........
....................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....
..................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....
.................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
.......xxxxxxx..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
......xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.....
......xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
.......xxxxxxx..xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
.................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
..................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....
....................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....
....................x..xxxxxxxxxx........
..........................xxxx...........
..........................xxxx...........
.........................................
.........................................
```

#### More readable version:

```
outchar (x,y)
   | x*x + y*y < 4.0 = 'x'
   | otherwise       = '.'

calc v w = outchar (iterate step (v,w) !! 1000)
   where step (x,y) = (x*x - y*y + v, 2*x*y + w)

main = mapM_ putStrLn [[calc x y
                        | x <- [-1.5, -1.45 .. 0.5]]
                       | y <- [1, 0.9 .. -1]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Python <del>197</del> 162

```
def m():
    for a in range(900):
        c=complex(a%30*.1-2,a/30*.1-1.5);z,i=c-c,0
        while i<28 and abs(z)<2:z,i=z*z+c,i+1
        if a%30==0:print
        print ".-+oxawOX "[i/3],
```

I'm interested in how you get rid of the white space in python.

Comment: Original was actually 163 if you convert 4 spaces to a single tab.

Comment: Re white space - you don't, that's why it's called significant

Comment: @johnc See my other (less readable) answer. Using functions inside of functions allows putting it all on one line. The trick is figuring out which functions to use. For example, by making the output only 2 levels, I was able to move the while loop into a reduce(). That's the kind of thing I was interested in.

Answer (score 6):

### Assembler

.COM Executable = 140 bytes

Source = 652 bytes

```
mov ax,13h
int 10h
mov bx,200
xor di,di
mov ax,0a000h
mov es,ax
l1:mov bp,320
mov [si],bx
fild w[si]
fisub w[v100]
fidiv w[v50]
l2:mov cx,1000
mov [si],bp
fild w[106h]
fisub w[si]
fidiv w[v80]
fld1
fsubp
fldz
fldz
l3:fld st(1)
fmul st(0)
fld st(1)
fmul st(0)
fld st(0)
fadd st(2)
fcomp d[v4]
fstsw ax
test ah,45h
jz l4
fsubp
fadd st(3)
fxch st(2)
fild w[v2]
fmulp st(1)
fmulp st(1)
fadd st(3)
loop l3
mov al,255
l5:fcompp
fcomp
stosb
dec bp
jnz l2
fcomp
dec bx
jnz l1
mov ah,7
int 21h
mov ax,3
int 10h
ret
l4:mov ax,-10
mul cx
fcompp
jmp l5
v100:dw 100
v50:dw 80
v80:dw 90
v4:dd 4.0
v2:dw 2
```

Answer (score 5):

**JavaScript (168/174 characters)**

**Rhino version (168 characters):**

```
m=1000;for(i=0;i<40;i++){l=[];for(j=0;j<80;j++){v=j/80*3-2,w=2-i/40*3,x=y=c=0;while(x*x+y*y<5&&c<m)t=x*x-y*y+v,y=2*x*y+w,x=t,c++;l.push(c==m?' ':'-')}print(l.join(''))}
```

**Firebug version (174 characters):**

```
m=1000;for(i=0;i<40;i++){l=[];for(j=0;j<80;j++){v=j/80*3-2,w=2-i/40*3,x=y=c=0;while(x*x+y*y<5&&c<m)t=x*x-y*y+v,y=2*x*y+w,x=t,c++;l.push(c==m?' ':'-')}console.log(l.join(''))}
```

Answer (score 5):

### And a dc entry - 152 chars

My usual madness in `dc`

```
Ak?4r/sa4r/sbA00sm[0*]sG_2sj[_3si[0ddsxsysk[lxd*lyd*-li+2lxly**lj+sysx1lxd*lyd*+
4!>G1lk1+dsklm<G*1=L]dsLx0klk1-vvnAklila+dsi1!<I]dsIxAPljlb+dsj2!<J]dsJx
```

test run:

```
bash-3.2$ dc -f mandel.dc 
10 20
000000000000000000000
000000000011111111111
000000001111111111111
000000111111115211111
000000111111555551111
000000555555555551111
000000111111555551111
000000111111115211111
000000001111111111111
000000000011111111111
000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Nothing should be able to compete with perl like that. Yuck! ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Ruby** - 139 chars *(Twitter-friendly)*

```
b,a=$*;a.to_i.times{|l|puts (0..b.to_i).map{|n|x=y=i=0;(x,y,i=x*x-y*y+n/38.0-1.5,2*x*y+l/14.0-1,i+1)until(x*x+y*y>4||i>78);(32+i).chr}*""}
```

`$ ruby mandelbrot.rb 80 32`

or as a single command line (134 chars including `ruby -e`)

```
ruby -e "32.times{|l|puts (0..78).map{|n|x=y=i=0;(x,y,i=x*x-y*y+n/38.0-1.5,2*x*y+l/14.0-1,i+1)until(x*x+y*y>4||i>78);(32+i).chr}*''}"
```

```
"###############################$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%&&')*/))*.o&%$$$$$$$$########"""""
############################$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%&''((*-G,*('&&%%$$$$$$$$$########""
#########################$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%&&'929-03ooL.+0:'&%%%%%$$$$$$$########
#####################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%&&&&&''()-1oooooooo/*('&&%%%%%%%$$$$$######
##################$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%&'''''''''())*,6oooooooo.*)((''&&&&&&&&%$$$#####
###############$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%&&'(+3:0.,++ooE6ooooooooooo?8o1j?8)(((()4/'&%$$$###
###########$$$$$$%%%%%%%%%%&&&&''(*1>ooo8oooooooooooooooooooooooo.3oooD/,'%%$$$##
#######$$$$%%%%%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&')8,,17ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooQ0)'&&%%$$$#
$$$$$$%&)(&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'''((*18oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooool*(('&%%$$$
$$%%%%&&*2*))((((25*(('''((()+F>=oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo1.(%%$$$
%%%%%&&'()*,1o47//5o5/?,+***+3oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.)(&%%$$$
%%%%&'''(*+-3ooooooooooom//-.oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo9+&%%$$$
&&(*+)))+-?ooooooooooooooooL5ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo8)&%%%$$$
'()*-X=U95ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*'&&%%%$$$
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo:.+)('&&%%%$$$
'()*-X=U95ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo*'&&%%%$$$
&&(*+)))+-?ooooooooooooooooL5ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo8)&%%%$$$
%%%%&'''(*+-3ooooooooooom//-.oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo9+&%%$$$
%%%%%&&'()*,1o47//5o5/?,+***+3oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.)(&%%$$$
$$%%%%&&*2*))((((25*(('''((()+F>=oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo1.(%%$$$
$$$$$$%&)(&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'''((*18oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooool*(('&%%$$$
#######$$$$%%%%%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&')8,,17ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooQ0)'&&%%$$$#
###########$$$$$$%%%%%%%%%%&&&&''(*1>ooo8oooooooooooooooooooooooo.3oooD/,'%%$$$##
###############$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%&&'(+3:0.,++ooE6ooooooooooo?8o1j?8)(((()4/'&%$$$###
##################$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%&'''''''''())*,6oooooooo.*)((''&&&&&&&&%$$$#####
#####################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%&&&&&''()-1oooooooo/*('&&%%%%%%%$$$$$######
#########################$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%&&'929-03ooL.+0:'&%%%%%$$$$$$$########
############################$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%&''((*-G,*('&&%%$$$$$$$$$########""
"###############################$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%&&')*/))*.o&%$$$$$$$$########"""""
"""""###############################$$$$$$$$$%%%&'*)'&&%%%$$$$$$$#######"""""""""
"""""""""#################################$$$$$$$%%%%%$$$$$#########"""""""""""""
""""""""""""""""#############################################""""""""""""""""""""
```

Answer (score 1):

### C# - 330

277 if you drop the using statement and remove the leading whitespace and line endings

```
int c,i,j,w=300,h=300,m=50;
using(var b=new Bitmap(w,h)){
 for(i=0;i<w;i++){
  for(j=0;j<h;j++){
   double x0=4.0*(i-w/2)/w-1,y0=4.0*(j-h/2)/h,x=0.0,y=0.0;
   for(c=0;x*x+y*y<=4.0&&c<m;c++){
    var t=x*x-y*y+x0;
    y=2.0*x*y+y0;x=t;
   }
   int v=c==m?255:c*10%255;
   b.SetPixel(i,j,Color.FromArgb(v,v,v));
  }
 }
}
```

Not record setting by a long shot - but fun to convert from the Python sample source and compress down beyond readable.

Answer (score 1):

**Python. 98 chars.**

```
for _ in range(526):z=0;exec"z=z*z+_%25*.1-2+_/25*.1j-1j;"*50;print[".#"[z.real<4],"\n"][_%25<1],
```

Prints something like this:

```
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . # # # # # . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # # # # # # . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # # # # # # # . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # # # # # # # . 
. . . . . . . . # # # . # # # # # # # # # # # . 
. . . . . . . # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # . 
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # . . 
. . . . . . . # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # . 
. . . . . . . . # # # . # # # # # # # # # # # . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # # # # # # # . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # # # # # # # . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # # # # # # # # . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . # # # # # . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . .
```

http://codepad.org/rNPrgQ3H